# Use of the Ubuntu Font in website design!

Tags: fonts, websites

Is it ok to use this font freely in a website you're creating for a school in the UK?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: **Yes it is.**

Long Answer: Please read the [license](https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/font-licence), especially the part "Permission & Conditions".

> This licence allows the licensed fonts to be used, studied, modified and redistributed freely. The fonts, including any derivative works, can be bundled, embedded, and redistributed provided the terms of this licence are met. The fonts and derivatives, however, cannot be released under any other licence.